# "result to" is also correct

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I don't understand why "result in" stands to be the only correct between the two.
"Result to", to me is also correct because I process it like; The entity or event resulted to is due to the affirmation preceding the preposition "to".

For example, I will transform the below equation to plain English.
1 + 1 = 2;

One plus one is equal to 2.

Therefore 2 is caused by 1 + 1.

"Result in" to me means the affirmation before the preposition happens within or affects the outcome rather than it causing the outcome.

1 + 1 causes 2, 2 is a result of adding 1 and 1 so 2 is equal to 1 + 1, 1 + 1 results to 2.

Comment: 2 is not "caused" by 1 and 1.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey why do you say that?

Comment: You might as well say that 2 is caused by 6/3 or 5-3.

Comment: When you looked this up in dictionaries, how were the example sentences worded - *result to* or *result in?*

Comment: @Davo they were worded as "result in", even Grammarly had "result to" highlighted as wrong,

Comment: 1 + 1 causes 2, 2 is a result of adding 1 and 1 so 2 is equal to 1 + 1, 1 + 1 results to 2. ;D

Comment: 1+1 does not result TO 2, it results IN 2. Perhaps you are thinking of resolve? 1+1 resolves TO 2.

Comment: @Davo  what does the following idiom mean to you "boil down to something"?

Comment: "Boil down to" does not mean "results to". "Results to" is not standard English. New questions should be posted as new questions, not as comments or answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic express is "result in"

> An increase in rainfall will result in more flooding.

It is not idiomatic to say "result to" in this context.

See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35305/result-in-or-result-to on our sister site.

You would not use "result in" or "result to" in the example you give.  You could say "one plus one is equal to two", or "one plus one equals two".  You can say "The result of adding one and one is two".  You would not say "two is caused by one plus one".

Comment: If you assume the idiom did not exist, then you are not speaking English.  So it would not be correct. Just because something is "logical" doesn't make it correct.